# Do sorcery points have any value at level 2?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, sorcerer

The [sorcerer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer) gains 2 sorcery points at 2nd level. However aside from trading those 2 points for another spell slot they seem to have no purpose as no skill that spends points is available until 3rd level.

Did I miss something or is it just effectively an extra spell slot?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### You are basically correct

There are two things you can do with sorcery points at level 2.

First, as you noted, you can take your 2 given points and make a level 1 spell slot, totaling 4 for the day.

Second, you can turn your level 1 spell slots into 1 sorcery point each. This seems to be pointless, as the only thing you could do from there is to turn another one into a point, then convert them back to level 1 slots for a total loss of one spell. Unfortunately, the wording

> You can never have more sorcery points than shown on the table for your level.

prevents you from creating a higher level slot than you have at this level (though the math does work out for levels 6, 7, and 8). Overall, I don't see a point to this, but it may be open to cheese somehow.

---

There's another potential bonus here. As a Wild Magic sorcerer, it's possible for a Surge to roll 99-00 and grant you your expended points back. With extraordinary luck, this could mean multiple additional slots in a day.

Comment: I would like to point out: gaining an additional 1st level spell slot here is about as powerful as the _Arcane Recovery_ feature of Wizards at this level. This is faster, as the Wizard feature requires a short rest, but Wizards can do their thing at 1st level.

Comment: @Javelin While you're correct, I'm not sure it's helpful as the question only mentions Sorcerers.

Comment: I feel like there is something gained in comparing one class feature to another class's feature to help reinforce its value. But it is your answer, so I will leave it to you to decide if it is relevant enough.